# How to run su commands like "adb shell wm density reset" from java code.They are working in genymotion but not on real rooted devices

Tags: java, android, shell

I am trying to run su commands like "adb shell wm density reset" from application java code.They are working in genymotion but not on real rooted devices.I have used Process,Process Builder and many possibilities but not found a way.They are working when I run same commands from terminal in my PC.Any help is appreciated.